# firefox 25 extjs 4 loading issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, extjs4

Is anyone experiencing any problems with running ExtJs 4.2.0 with Firefox version 25.0.1?  ExtJs 4.2.0 is running fine in Chrome and IE.  Frequently, when I load up ExtJs 4.2.0 with the latest version of Firefox (ver. 25.0.1), sometimes the browser loads completely and sometimes the Firefox browser renders partially.  When it renders partially, I look in the Firefox console and see errors, such as "TypeError: url is not defined."

Sometimes, in the Firefox console, I see console errors, such as "ReferenceError: "[variable] is not defined."  However, when I open the console in Chrome and IE, no console errors exist.

Before the recent Firefox update to version 25.0.1, the Firefox browser did not have problems loading the web app with ExtJs 4.2.0.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/bryntum/support/tickets/777-error-on-upgrade-from-ext-js-4-1-1-to-4-2-0-and-from-scheduller-+-gant-2-1-14-to-2-2-3#/activity/ticket: